# Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '' in a call to 'postMessage'

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, vimeo

I have the following script:

```
 post : function (action, value, iframe) {
    var data = {
      method: action
    };

    if (value) {
      data.value = value;
    }

    // Source URL
    var iframeSrc = jQuery(iframe).attr('src').split('?')[0];

    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), vimeoGAJS.getUrl(iframeSrc));
  },
```

I am using a third party plug-in to track vimeo videos on my website and I want to track video interaction as an event in Google Analytics.  I am getting the following error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '' in a call to 'postMessage'.

Comment: What does `vimeoGAJS.getUrl(iframeSrc)` give you?  You need to pass the `origin` of the window (iframe) you are posting a message to.  eg: `http://example.org`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by removing the 'https:' from the src URL of the iframe....it should start '//player.vimeo.....'